# Question shows as Edited 4m ago but nothing has been edited

Tags: support

so on my Interesting questions Tab I see

[image]

so I [clicked it to see the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790451/ms-excel-vba-i-need-to-import-a-worksheet-from-one-excel-file-to-another) but it seems like nothing has been edited

Also, I don't see anything in the [user's activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=activity&sort=all)

So what's up with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[10k+ user can see that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193994/575376): One deleted answer in that question got edited from bluefeet that time.

[image: deleted answer]

Comment: yea thats the missing puzzle